# dbt: sql_header macro limitations vs query-comment

Tags: dbt

Dbt has a configuration setting for `sql_header` that ostensibly is for injecting udf's at runtime into a model statement. Unfortunately, it seems calling a macro is unsupported. In addition, ephemeral materializations are un-impacted by this setting. I created a setting called `sql_footer` but at the end of a sql statement and has similarly limitations.

Would it be reasonable tweak the query_header [code](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/blob/dev/marian-anderson/core/dbt/adapters/base/query_headers.py) to support injecting raw sql in addition to comment blocks, say by adding an execution boolean to the config dictionary?

```
  dbt/core/dbt/adapters/base/query_headers.py
  def add(self, sql: str) -> str:
    if not self.query_comment:
        return sql

    if self.append:
        # replace last ';' with '<comment>;'
        sql = sql.rstrip()
        if sql[-1] == ';':
            sql = sql[:-1]
            return '{}\n{} {} {};'.format(sql, block_start, self.query_comment.strip(), block_end)
            vs
            return '{}\n/* {} */;'.format(sql, self.query_comment.strip())
```

I understand any reticence to injecting sql into sql, my use-cases are very much system level configurations that a model developer would never come into contact with and would ideally be controlled through cicd. Our etl has different implementations that require different staging filters depending on the environments. I'd prefer to inject a line or two of sql rather than having to duplicate models for each implementation.
for ex:

```
dbt_project.yml
models:
  - foo:
      query_comment:
        comment: "{{ var('ops_filter', default_filter()) }}"
        executable: True
        append: True
```

````
stg_foo.sql
with source as (Select *
from {{ source('foo') }})
select id 
from source
### inject footer sql here ###
where $date_param between dbt_valid_to and dbt_valid_from
|where 1=1
|where dms_updated_at::date=$date_param```


Any advice is appreciated, love this project!
````

Answer (score 1):

Based on your use case, it sounds like you're interested in functionality along the lines of this older issue:
https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/issues/1096. We closed that issue in May due to lack of interest from the community, but that doesn't mean that people don't run into this problem (and dbtonic answers for it) today.

As I see it, the best answer is to include a macro `{{ footer_sql() }}` at the bottom of your models, which could then dynamically include (or not) your environment-specific logic:

```
{% macro footer_sql(date_param) %}

{% if target.name == 'ci' %}
where {{ date_param }} between dbt_valid_to and dbt_valid_from

{% elif target.name == 'prod' %}
where 1=1

{% elif target.name == 'dev' %}
where dms_updated_at::date= {{ date_param }}

{% endif %}

{% endmacro %}
```

Last but not least, I just want to address a few of the things you mentioned:

> Unfortunately, it seems calling a macro is unsupported.

You can absolutely include Jinja macros in `set_sql_header` calls, as long as those macros compile to SQL. This is how many users create UDFs on BigQuery.

> In addition, ephemeral materializations are un-impacted by this setting.

That's correct. The purpose of SQL headers is to interpolate SQL that will precede the `create view as`/`create table as` DDL; since ephemeral models aren't materialized as database objects, they have no DDL to precede.

Comment: First and foremost, thank you for such a quick and thorough reply.

Comment: I've toyed back and forth with the idea of a common macro,customizing materializations, monkey patching the python code. For openers, we'll go with your suggestion and revisit if it becomes a hardship.

As to `set_sql_header`, this would be set in the config of a model directly as opposed to extending a materialization?

As to 1096, I was thinking a patch would be useful as far as the refactoring implied [here](https://github.com/fishtown-analytics/dbt/pull/1967#pullrequestreview-329137969).